# Alart or modal screen javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, alert

I am developing a site where there is a part where I perform a  zip code query, when I give "TAB" or simply click off the field to inform data to the query is performed the event (I'm execulting my JavaScript code in the onblur event in my inputbox). However, I need a "modal" screen or "alert" that should appear during the waiting time of the query.

already tried using the methods below, but I did not succeed, do not work in onblur event and not in onclick:

```
 $ ('# BuscaCEP') modal ('show.');
 $ ('# BuscaCEP') modal ('hide');.
```

someone would have a tip?

my geral code:

```
 <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php //inputbox to the query from the onblur ?>
                            <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>
                            </label>

                            <div class="input-box input-box-bkg-lage-small">

                                <input type="text" name="postcode"
                                       value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                                       title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip"
                                       onblur="consultacep(this.value)"
                                       OnKeyPress="formatNumber('#####-###', this, event)" maxlength="9"
                                       class="form-control validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>"/>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </li>


<script type="text/javascript">

//Javascript Code
    function consultacep(cep) {

        cep = cep.replace(/\D/g, "")
        url = "http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/" + cep + ".js"
        s = document.createElement('script')
        s.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8')
        s.src = url
        document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s);


     //where the the loading screen should be performed
        $('#buscaCEP').modal('show');
    }

    function openWindow() {
        $('#buscaCEP').open();
    }

    function correiocontrolcep(valor) {
        if (valor.erro) {
            alert('Cep não encontrado');
            return;
        }


        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                document.getElementById('Street').value = valor.logradouro
                document.getElementById('bairro').value = valor.bairro
                document.getElementById('city').value = valor.localidade
                document.getElementById("region_id").value = xmlhttp.responseText;

                //where the the loading screen should be terminated
                $('#buscaCEP').modal('hide');
            }
        }


        var url = "<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>";
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "buscaUF.php?uf=" + valor.uf, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>
```

**with the help of Leopoldo Negro, arrived in the following situations:**

**Modal screen:**

```
    <!-- Modal  -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="buscaCEP" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Loading...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**inputbox:**

```
<li class="fields">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php //começa o cep e dados região ?>
                    <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>
                    </label>

                    <div class="input-box input-box-bkg-lage-small">

                        <input type="text" name="postcode"
                               value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                               title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip"
                               onblur="consultacep(this.value)"
                               OnKeyPress="formatNumber('#####-###', this, event)" maxlength="9"
                               class="form-control validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>"/>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </li>
```

**call the event:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {


                $('input[name="zip"]').blur(function(){
                    consultacep(this.value);
                });
            });

        </script>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    function consultacep(cep) {

        cep = cep.replace(/\D/g, "")
        url = "http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/" + cep + ".js"
        s = document.createElement('script')
        s.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8')
        s.src = url
        document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s);

        $('#buscaCEP').modal('show');

    }

    function openWindow() {
        $('#buscaCEP').open();
    }

    function correiocontrolcep(valor) {
        if (valor.erro) {
            alert('Cep não encontrado');
            return;
        }


        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                document.getElementById('Street').value = valor.logradouro
                document.getElementById('bairro').value = valor.bairro
                document.getElementById('city').value = valor.localidade
                /*document.getElementById('region_id').value=valor.uf*/
                /*document.getElementById('uf').value=valor.uf*/
                document.getElementById("region_id").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                //where the the loading screen should be performed
                $('#buscaCEP').modal('hide');

            }
        }


        var url = "<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>";
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "buscaUF.php?uf=" + valor.uf, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

**but still can not bring up a modal screen =/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everybody can not do two ways suggested above then did something basic that worked, I'm posting in order to help others!

created a div to a popup:

```
<DIV id="popup">
                        <span style="color: #0871B5;font-size: 20px ">BUSCANDO CEP!</span>
                        <br/>
                        <img src="<?php echo str_replace('index.php/' ,'',$this->getBaseUrl() . 'skin/frontend/default/TW/Images_TW/loader.gif') ?>"/>
                    </DIV>
```

and open it in javascript functions:

```
<script>

    function fechar(){
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function abrir(){
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout ("fechar()", 3000);
    }


    function consultacep(cep) {
        abrir();
        cep = cep.replace(/\D/g, "")
        url = "http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/" + cep + ".js"
        s = document.createElement('script')
        s.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8')
        s.src = url
        document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s);

    }

    function correiocontrolcep(valor) {
        if (valor.erro) {
            alert('Cep não encontrado');
            return;
        }

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('Street').value = valor.logradouro
                document.getElementById('bairro').value = valor.bairro
                document.getElementById('city').value = valor.localidade
                /*document.getElementById('region_id').value=valor.uf*/
                /*document.getElementById('uf').value=valor.uf*/
                document.getElementById("region_id").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                fechar();
            }
        }
        var url = "<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>";
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "buscaUF.php?uf=" + valor.uf, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#zip').blur(function(){
    consultacep(this.value);
});
```

This will bind the onblur event programmatically with *jQuery*.

Note: Make sure the item with id `buscaCEP` exists.

**Edit:**

The original error comes from the place where you define your functions, when "onblur" event triggers the callback is undefined and it triggers an error.
Try to add your javascript on the header of the website or use the method I provided for waiting the DOM to load.
Do not redefine the blur event callback, just use one method.
[simple example](http://www.bootply.com/wyfbK9sWer)

Comment: thank you, however it was not I wanted :(
 what I'm needing is to open a modal screen while referring to the CEP and when the query finish this modal close it alone

Comment: by modal screen do you mean a new window? or just a dialog inside the current web?

Comment: just a dialog inside the current web

Comment: Then my answer should work because you are calling `$('#buscaCEP').modal('show');` inside `consultacep()` and `$('#buscaCEP').modal('hide');` inside the ajax callback.

Comment: hey Leopoldo, I posted the code up there, I think I applied your tips or put understand wrong or did not work :/

Comment: added to the normal screen called the simple way you showed me, I put the modal screen on the <li> tag zip-cod alias inputbox, I copied your code and not to hovesse doubt but still did not work, did not call the modal screen, Look, my dcodigo was so dai: http://www.bootply.com/3ZVZfnHbJX
I missed the call something somewhere yet?

Comment: can you provide a live example of your website? there is php on the code and I can't tell you what is the exact error.

Comment: not stayed a site anywhere because still in development but códigod and all this page at this link: http://www.bootply.com/3ZVZfnHbJX

Note: I am developing this page in Magento platform.